# How to access match inside mapStatetoProps

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I access `match` prop inside `mapStateToProps`?

```
import React from "react";
import "./collectionpage.styles.scss";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { selectCollection } from "../../redux/shop/shop.selector";
import { useMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import Collectionitem from
  "../../components/collection-items/Collectionitem.component";
   
const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
  const match = useMatch();
  const { title, items } = collection;

  return (
    <div className="collection-page">
      <h2 className="title">{title}</h2>
      <div className="items">
        {items.map(item => <Collectionitem key={item.id} item={item}/>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

mapStatetoProps = (state) => {
  return ({
    collection: selectCollection(match.params.colletionID)(state)
  })
} 

export default connect(mapStatetoProps)(CollectionPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

`mapStatetoProps`  allow you pass owner props to. So you can pass `match` to a component. in this case is `CollectionPage`

```
const ComponentA = () => {
    const match = useMatch();
    return (<CollectionPage match={match}/>)
}
```

then:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
      return {
       collection: ownProps.match.params.colletionID
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

## `react-router-dom@5`

Since it appears you are using `react-router-dom@5` you'll have the [`withRouter`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component (HOC) available to you which can inject the [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props). I've often combined this with the `connect` HOC to first wrap and inject the route props so they are accessible within the `connect` HOC.

Example:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { selectCollection } from "../../redux/shop/shop.selector";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
  ....
}

mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  collection: selectCollection(props.match.params.colletionID)(state),
}); 

export default withRouter(
  connect(mapStateToProps)(CollectionPage)
);
```

Since you are also using Redux you may also find the [`compose`](https://redux.js.org/api/compose) function very handy here to compose all the HOCs over the component you want to decorate. It serves as a way to "unnest" all the HOCs your components may be using

Example:

```
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { selectCollection } from "../../redux/shop/shop.selector";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
  ....
}

mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  collection: selectCollection(props.match.params.colletionID)(state),
}); 

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(CollectionPage);
```

## `react-router-dom@6`

If using `react-router-dom@6` you'll need to create your own custom `withRouter` replacement since it was removed in v6.

Example:

```
import { useParams, /* other hooks */ } from 'react-router-dom';

const withRouter = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const params = useParams();
  // etc... other react-router-dom v6 hooks

  return (
    <WrappedComponent
      {...props}
      params={params}
      // etc...
    />
  );
};
```

...

```
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { selectCollection } from "../../redux/shop/shop.selector";
import { withRouter } from "../path/to/withRouter";

const CollectionPage = ({ collection }) => {
  ....
}

mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  collection: selectCollection(props.params.colletionID)(state),
}); 

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(CollectionPage);
```

Comment: actually i am using `react-router-dom`  : "^6.2.2"

Comment: @VishalSangole No worries. Same pattern applies but you'll create a custom `withRouter` HOC. I've updated my answer.